# Prism 8.0 register type with injection constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, prism, constructor-injection

In Prism 6.2 I registered the repository type as follows:

```
Container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Data.RepositoryBase<>), new InjectionConstructor(path));
```

When updating to Prism 8, I substitute the above code by this:

```
containerRegistry.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Data.RepositoryBase<>));
```

But this method does not allow an `InjectionConstructor`. How can I pass the parameters that the repository class needs in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

In [Prism 7.1.0](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.1.0) a container abstraction was introduced to unify the implementation.

> Added new `Prism.Ioc` namespace to handle DI container abstractions. Interacting with the container is now done via the `IContainerProvider` and the `IContainerRegistry` interfaces. The `IContainerProvider` interface is used to resolve services from the container. The `IContainerRegistry` is used to register types with the container.

However, the **common** container interfaces cannot provide a superset of all **individual** features of the supported containers. Nevertheless, you can still access the underlying container using the `GetContainer` method to leverage all of its features.

> Access to the actual DI container can be achieved by using the `GetContainer()` extension method off of the `IContainerRegistry` and `IContainerProvider` interfaces.

So for your example, you could use the same code as before with the underlying container:

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Data.RepositoryBase<>), new InjectionConstructor(path));
```